# Subfolders not being compiled for dev

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon, ts-node

I am using TypeScript to create my nodejs application, which is working fine inasmuch as the `index.ts` is being compiled and executed successfully, but the TypeScript files in subfolders are being ignored and don't form part of the dev watch.

Can anyone help out? I use `yarn start` to run my app in dev mode. My scripts from `package.json` look like this:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "yarn run build:live",
  "build": "rm -rf dist && tsc",
  "build:live": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node -- ./src/index.ts"
}
```

And my `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "target": "es2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/**.ts",
    "test/**/**.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I have tried using `"build:live": "nodemon --exec ./node_modules/.bin/ts-node --project tsconfig.json"` as my dev script but this causes the compiler to hang.

Answer (score 0):

`ts-node` will only execute files that are transitively required or imported by your main file `src/index.ts`.  You can use the `--files` option to make it include all files specified in `tsconfig.json` in the compilation, but this only helps to declare things, not to define them at runtime.  See [the documentation](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing).  If you need to execute all files without using require or import, consider running your project using a different tool.